# Input 0 of layer conv2d is incompatible with layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1 but received input with shape [None, 64, 64, 3]

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm running a model on EMNIST (128x128 gray-scale images) and I'm having trouble with understanding how to properly load data into Tensorflow for modeling.

I was following the flower example provided by TensorFlow (https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/image_feature_vector) **except for the CNN structure** until suddenly model.fit() failed with the error 
 `Input 0 of layer conv2d_120 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1 but received input with shape [None, 64, 64, 3]`

## Loading the Dataset

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

batch_size = 32
image_w = 64
image_h = 64
seed = 123
```

```
data_dir = 'B:\Datasets\EMNIST Digital Number & Digits\OriginalDigits'

train_df = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=seed,
  image_size=(image_w,image_h),
  batch_size=batch_size)

val_df = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation", #Same exact code block ... this is the only line of difference
  seed=seed,
  image_size=(image_w,image_h),
  batch_size=batch_size)
```

> Found 10160 files belonging to 10 classes. 
> Using 8128 files for training. 
> Found 10160 files belonging to 10 classes. 
> Using 2032 files for validation.

### Confirmation that the data loaded correctly

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
for images, labels in train_df.take(1): #Take subsets the dataset into at most __1__ element (Seems to randomly create it)
    for i in range(9):
        ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
        plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
        plt.title(labels[i].numpy().astype("str"))
        plt.axis("off")
```

## Processing the dataset into tf.data.Dataset object

```
class_labels = train_df.class_names
num_classes = len(class_labels)
print(class_labels,num_classes)
```

> ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'] 10

```
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

train_df_modeling = train_df.cache().shuffle(len(train_df)) #Load training data into memory cache + shuffle all 10160 images
val_df_modeling = val_df.cache().shuffle(len(train_df)) #Load validation data into memory cache
```

## Define model

```
#Model from https://www.kaggle.com/henseljahja/simple-tensorflow-cnn-98-8
model = keras.models.Sequential([

    layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(image_h, image_w, 1)), #(64,64,1)
    layers.Conv2D(64, 7, padding='same', activation='relu'),    
    layers.GaussianNoise(0.2),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2),
    layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding="SAME"),
    layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding="SAME"),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2),
    layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding="SAME"),
    layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding="SAME"),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(units=256, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dropout(0.5),
    layers.Dense(units=128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dropout(0.5),
    layers.Dense(units=64, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dropout(0.5),    
    keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'), #10 outputs [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
])

model.summary()
```

> Model: "sequential"
> _________________________________________________________________
> Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
> =================================================================
> rescaling (Rescaling)        (None, 64, 64, 1)         0         
> _________________________________________________________________
> conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 64, 64, 64)        640       
> _________________________________________________________________
> max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 32, 32, 64)        0         
> _________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 32, 32, 128)       73856     
> _________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 32, 32, 128)       147584    
> _________________________________________________________________
> max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 16, 16, 128)       0         
> _________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 128)       147584    
> _________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 128)       147584    
> _________________________________________________________________
> max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 8, 8, 128)         0         
> _________________________________________________________________
> flatten (Flatten)            (None, 8192)              0         
> _________________________________________________________________
> dense (Dense)                (None, 256)               2097408   
> _________________________________________________________________
> dropout (Dropout)            (None, 256)               0         
> _________________________________________________________________
> dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 128)               32896     
> _________________________________________________________________
> dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 128)               0         
> _________________________________________________________________
> dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 64)                8256      
> _________________________________________________________________
> dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 64)                0         
> _________________________________________________________________
> dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 10)                650       
> =================================================================
> Total params: 2,656,458
> Trainable params: 2,656,458
> Non-trainable params: 0

---

## Training the model

```
model.compile(
    loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
    optimizer = 'nadam',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

result = model.fit(train_df_modeling,
                   validation_data=val_df_modeling,
                   epochs=20,
                   verbose=1)
```

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1 but received input with shape [None, 64, 64, 3]

I understand that my problem is related to shape and that [None, 64, 64, 3] is [batch_size, width, height, channels] but I have the following questions:

1. Why does it expect the input shape to `have value 1`? Shouldn't the Conv2D layer be expecting an image?
2. Why does my input have 3 channels? I told it the input has only 1 channel. 
   Note: Attempting to remove the rescale layer and simply have Conv2D be the initial layer still gives this same error message of expecting value 1 but got 64x64x3

Answer (score 2):

Well ... in the midst of typing the last section about questions I had, I came about the solution at question #2.

My data (although it is gray-scale data) was being read by Tensorflow as RGB because I never specified.

## Solution

Read data in as gray-scale

Documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image_dataset_from_directory

Argument of interest: `color_mode='grayscale'`

## Modification to my code to get it working:

Only needed to change 1 block of code (2 variables)

```
data_dir = 'B:\Datasets\EMNIST Digital Number & Digits\OriginalDigits'

train_df = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=seed,
  image_size=(image_w,image_h),
  batch_size=batch_size,
  color_mode='grayscale') #<---- This is was the missing link

val_df = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=seed,
  image_size=(image_w,image_h),
  batch_size=batch_size,
  color_mode='grayscale') #<---- This is was the missing link
```

Though this solution fixes the model & allows the code to execute ... **can anyone answer question #1?** I'm still curious why it believed it needed an input to `have value 1` when I believe the input should have been an image.

Comment: The error just says that the last axis (-1) of your input shape (image_h, image_w, 1) should be 1, which is correct, your last axis of the shape of your image was 3 instead of 1.

Comment: That makes so much more sense, thank you for pointing that out.